# Suppress only the actual make command and final print statement

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a program that outputs things--numbers--to stdout.

The program runs with `make run input.txt 0.87 > output_file` in an auto-grader (this is for an assignment). The program must run this way (even though it is not really supposed to be possible for a make file).

However, I got it working with the help of a SO question on here. Here is my makefile:

```
pr.exe : main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 $^ -o $@

run:
    @./pr.exe $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))


%:
    @:

compile : pr.exe
.PHONY : compile
```

There is just one problem: the command `make run input.txt 0.87` outputs, in addition to the program output, the final line:

```
make: 'input.txt' is up to date.
```

---

How do I suppress this line in my make file such that only the program output is redirected into the file?

It must run properly with **only** the following command (no make arguments, nada):

```
make run input.txt 0.87 > some_output_file.txt
```

Comment: This really sounds like an instance of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). For example, the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) itself says that "`MAKECMDGOALS` should be used only in special circumstances".

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar or are you saying that these inputs can be passed to the makefile some other way?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar right: the autograder is already written with that particular command in mind: `make run input1 input2` (so that is why this is the way it is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printing of `message` is disabled by `-s` option of make:

https://github.com/mturk/gnumake/blob/9c3fecf4dd76a8c802055d9bd3689d0c6c5d6167/remake.c#L229

```
  if (!rebuilding_makefiles
  /* If the update_status is zero, we updated successfully
     or not at all.  G->changed will have been set above if
     any commands were actually started for this goal.  */
  && file->update_status == 0 && !g->changed
  /* Never give a message under -s or -q.  */
  && !silent_flag && !question_flag)
    message (1, ((file->phony || file->cmds == 0)
             ? _("Nothing to be done for '%s'.")
             : _("'%s' is up to date.")),
         file->name);
```

The `silent_flag` is set by `-s` command line option of make:

https://github.com/mturk/gnumake/blob/9c3fecf4dd76a8c802055d9bd3689d0c6c5d6167/main.c#L412

```
/* Nonzero means do not print commands to be executed (-s).  */

int silent_flag;
{ 's', flag, &silent_flag, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, "silent" },
```

And also it is set in https://github.com/mturk/gnumake/blob/9c3fecf4dd76a8c802055d9bd3689d0c6c5d6167/file.c#L752

```
  f = lookup_file (".SILENT");
  if (f != 0 && f->is_target)
    {
      if (f->deps == 0)
        silent_flag = 1;
      else
        for (d = f->deps; d != 0; d = d->next)
          for (f2 = d->file; f2 != 0; f2 = f2->prev)
            f2->command_flags |= COMMANDS_SILENT;
    }
```

This is parsing of `.SILENT` special target documented in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html

> `.SILENT`
>
> If you specify prerequisites for .SILENT, then make will not print the
>   recipe used to remake those particular files before executing them.
>   The recipe for .SILENT is ignored.
>
> If mentioned as a target with no prerequisites, .SILENT says not to
>   print any recipes before executing them. This usage of ‘.SILENT’ is
>   supported only for historical compatibility. We recommend you use the
>   more selective ways to silence specific recipes. See Recipe Echoing.
>   If you want to silence all recipes for a particular run of make, use
>   the ‘-s’ or ‘--silent’ option (see Options Summary).

So, try to add `.SILENT` special target to your Makefile without any additional prerequisites. (Solution is not tested by me.)

```
.SILENT:
```

Comment: I stumbled upon `.SILENT` when looking through the GNU Make documentation, but it never occurred to me that it might also disable this particular message. Kudos to you. (also : it works)

Comment: @osgx ha! .SILENT + : did it.  Thank you! (missing the colon all night...).